# How to write Ternary operation condition in android XML while data binding

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

How to write the equivalent expression of Ternary operation in android xml while using data binding.

```
android:visibility="@{(assessmentquestionanswer.type.equals(@string/editText_type)?  View.VISIBLE : View.GONE) || (assessmentquestionanswer.type.equals(@string/date)?  View.VISIBLE : View.GONE)}"
```

Currently I am getting an error message as 
**must be able to find a common parent for boolean and int**

Comment: isn't `android:visibility="a|b"` working?

Comment: `yourVisibleObject.setVisibility (yourVisibleObject.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE ?  View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);` with java (not in xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of implementation is wrong, your current condition is like

```
(assessmentquestionanswer.type.equals(@string/editText_type)?  View.VISIBLE : View.GONE) || (assessmentquestionanswer.type.equals(@string/date)?  View.VISIBLE : View.GONE)
                          View.VISIBLE                                                   ||                            View.VISIBLE
```

which is not right. It should be

```
android:visibility="@{(assessmentquestionanswer.type.equals(@string/editText_type) || assessmentquestionanswer.type.equals(@string/date)) ?  View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
android:visibility="@{(assessmentquestionanswer.type.equals(@string/editText_type) || assessmentquestionanswer.type.equals(@string/date))?  View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```